# Unable to hide/show one accordian panel tab on the basis of radio button selection under another tab

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, accordion

I have a xhtml in which I have an accordian panel with 2 tabs :

```
    <p:accordionPanel id="accordianPanel">

        <p:tab title="Type of movement" id="typeOfMovementTab"


              <typeofmovement:typeOfMovementPanelGuiData id="typeOfMovementPanelGuiData"
                    typeOfMovementPanelGuiData="#{cc.attrs.searchCriteriaSecuritiesEntriesViewGUIData.typeOfMovementPanelGuiData}" />
            </f:subview>
        </p:tab>

         <p:tab title="Client" id="clientTab" rendered="#{cc.attrs.searchCriteriaSecuritiesEntriesViewGUIData.typeOfMovementPanelGuiData.typeOfMovement == 'ONLY_RECOUNCILE_MOVEMENT'}"

                <customer:customerCPanelGUIData id="customerCPanelGUIData"
                    customerCPanelGUIData="#{cc.attrs.searchCriteriaSecuritiesEntriesViewGUIData.customerCPanelGUIData}" />
            </f:subview>

         </p:tab>
 <p:accordionPanel>
```

Now I want to render **clientTab** on the basis of radio button selection inside **typeOfMovementTab**. I tried to do ajax:update  inside typeOfMovementPanelGuiData (typeOfMovementTab) as below but it's not causing any impact on radion button change :

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="typeOfMovementSelectOneRadio" value="#{cc.attrs.typeOfMovementPanelGuiData.typeOfMovement}" layout="custom">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{typeOfMovementPanelMsg['typeofmovement.onlyclientmovements']}" itemValue="ONLY_CLIENT_MOVEMENT"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{typeOfMovementPanelMsg['typeofmovement.onlyunreconciledmovements']}" itemValue="ONLY_RECOUNCILE_MOVEMENT"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{typeOfMovementPanelMsg['typeofmovement.bothclientandunreconciledmovements']}" itemValue="BOTH_CLIENT_RECOUNCILE_MOVEMENT"/>
            <p:ajax event="click" process="@this" update=":searchAndConsultSecurityForm:searchCriteriaSecuritiesEntriesViewGUIDataPanel:accordianPanel:clientTab"/>
        </p:selectOneRadio>
```

I  have seen below warning in console :

```
WARNING: Can not update component   "org.primefaces.component.tabview.Tab"  with id
```

"searchAndConsultSecurityForm:searchCriteriaSecuritiesEntriesViewGUIDataPanel:a
ccordianPanel:clientPanel" without a attached renderer. Expression ":searchAndCo
nsultSecurityForm:searchCriteriaSecuritiesEntriesViewGUIDataPanel:accordianPanel
:clientPanel" referenced from "searchAndConsultSecurityForm:searchCriteriaSecuri
tiesEntriesViewGUIDataPanel:accordianPanel:typeOfMovement:typeOfMovementPanelGui
Data:typeOfMovementSelectOneRadio"

**Update** :

I got it working by using `f:ajax` and `render`

```
 <p:selectOneRadio id="typeOfMovementSelectOneRadio" value="#{cc.attrs.typeOfMovementPanelGuiData.typeOfMovement}" layout="custom">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{typeOfMovementPanelMsg['typeofmovement.onlyclientmovements']}" itemValue="ONLY_CLIENT_MOVEMENT"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{typeOfMovementPanelMsg['typeofmovement.onlyunreconciledmovements']}" itemValue="ONLY_RECOUNCILE_MOVEMENT"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{typeOfMovementPanelMsg['typeofmovement.bothclientandunreconciledmovements']}" itemValue="BOTH_CLIENT_RECOUNCILE_MOVEMENT"/>
            <f:ajax event="click" process="@this" render="@form"/>
        </p:selectOneRadio>
```

Comment: please correct your code, formatting etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try with this template:

```
<p:outputPanel id="parentPanel">
<p:outputPanel id="childPanel">
    THE ELEMS THAT RENDER THE HIDDEN ELEMS: "render="THE id OF YOUR HIDDEN ELEMS TO SHOW""
</p:outputPanel>
<p:outputPanel id="customPanel">
    <p:outputPanel rendered="YOUR RENDER CONDITION">
        YOUR HIDDEN ELEMS           
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:outputPanel></p:outputPanel>
```